# How to make sure navigationcontroller won't reuse a controller

Tags: ios, memory, uiview, uinavigationcontroller

I am using navigationcontroller to let the user navigate between different views. The problem is that the navigationcontroller, in some way, reuses a view I already popped out, but I don't want this behavior.

How can I be sure that the navigationcontroller won't keep anything in memory? nor the xib file?

THank you.

**EDIT**

Here is the code I am using to push

```
VisualViewController *visualController = [[VisualViewController alloc] init];
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.4;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
transition.type = kCATransitionReveal;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;
transition.delegate = self;
[self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:@"GoToVisualAnimation"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:visualController animated:NO];
[visualController release];
```

and to pop:

```
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.75;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
transition.type = kCATransitionReveal;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;
transition.delegate = self;
[self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

Hope it helps.

Thank you!

Comment: Always helps if you show some code.

Comment: Oh sorry.. I just added the code

Answer (score 0):

This will ensure you are popping the right View Controller.

```
for(UIViewController *myVC in self.navigationController.viewControllers){
NSLog(@"Current View Controller@%@",myVC);
if ([myVC isKindOfClass:[[NameOftheViewControllerYouSeek] class]]) {
NSLog(@"You found the right View Controller");
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
[self.navigationController popToViewController:myVC animated:YES];    
}
```